# How can I update a DateTime?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a realtime chat app with fisebase. The problem is that the time of a sent message does not update and I don't know what else can I do.

Here's some part of my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:heyou/helper/constants.dart';
import 'package:heyou/screens/conversation_screen/send_menu_items.dart';
import 'package:heyou/services/database.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class ConversationScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final String chatScreenId;
  ConversationScreen(this.chatScreenId);

  @override
  _ConversationScreenState createState() => _ConversationScreenState();
}

class _ConversationScreenState extends State<ConversationScreen> {

  DateTime _currentDate = new DateTime.now();

  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController messageController = new TextEditingController();

  Stream chatMessageStream;

  Widget chatMessageList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatMessageStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70.0),
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return MessageTile(
              snapshot.data.documents[index].data['message'],
              snapshot.data.documents[index].data['sendBy'] == Constants.myName,
              snapshot.data.documents[index].data['time'],
              snapshot.data.documents[index].data['messageTimeTile'],
            );
          }
        ) : Container();
      },
    );
  }

  sendMessage() {
    if(messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      Map<String, dynamic> messageMap = {
      'message': messageController.text,
      'sendBy': Constants.myName,
      'time': DateTime.now().toString(),
      'messageTimeTile': new DateFormat.Hms().format(_currentDate).toString(),
      };
      databaseMethods.addConversationMessages(widget.chatScreenId, messageMap);
      messageController.text = '';
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    databaseMethods.getConversationMessages(widget.chatScreenId).then((value) {
      
      setState(() {
        chatMessageStream = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  } 
}
```

And here's my database code:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
class DatabaseMethods {
  getUserByUsername(String username) async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('name', isEqualTo: username).getDocuments();
  }

  getUserByUserEmail(String userEmail) async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection('users').where('email', isEqualTo: userEmail).getDocuments();
  }

  uploadUserInfo(userMap) {
    Firestore.instance.collection('users').add(userMap);
  }

  createChatScreen(String chatScreenId, chatScreenMap) {
    Firestore.instance.collection('ChatScreen').document(chatScreenId).setData(chatScreenMap).catchError((e){
      print(e.toString());
    });
  }

  addConversationMessages(String chatScreenId, messageMap) {
    Firestore.instance.collection('ChatScreen').document(chatScreenId).collection('chats').add(messageMap)
    .catchError((e){
      print(e.toString());
    });
  }

  getConversationMessages(String chatScreenId) async {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('ChatScreen').document(chatScreenId).collection('chats')
    .orderBy('time', descending: true).snapshots();
  }

  getHomeScreen(String userName) async {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('ChatScreen').where('users', arrayContains: userName).snapshots();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to fix it by myself but I can't, that's why I'm here.

Comment: Instead of `DateFormat.Hms().format(_currentDate).toString()` you probably want to write `DateFormat.Hms().format(DateTime.now()).toString()`

Comment: `DateTime _currentDate = new DateTime.now();`

Comment: You are initialising the `_currentDate` only once, so the value won't change after that. Either you have to re-assign the variable in sendMessage each time or do it like my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `_currentDate`, it is never updated. Consequently, it will always be the time at which the `State` object was created. You can either use Midhun MP's suggestion in the comments, or replacing `DateTime _currentDate = new DateTime.now();` with `DateTime get _currentDate => DateTime.now();` to always get a copy of the current date, in case you use it in multiple places.